# JScrollPane: How to move the scroll bar to the left and have the viewport align on the right

Tags: java, vertical-alignment, jscrollpane

If I put the JScrollPane scroll bar on the left side, the left part of the viewport is placed under the scrollbar.

```
jScrollPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

How to align the viewport to the right of the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here : http://forums.codeguru.com/
Thanks to Rafke.
It works fine.

```
jScrollPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout() {
    @Override
    public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
        JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane) parent;
        scrollPane.setComponentOrientation(
            ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            super.layoutContainer(parent);
            scrollPane.setComponentOrientation(
                ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    }
});
```